# Angular2 component not rendered

Tags: typescript, angular

I have experience in AngularJS and am starting to learn Angular2. I am at the very beginning of my learning journey, but I'm already stuck.

I can get one of my components to render, but not the other. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and TypeScript 1.5 beta. Here's the source:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 Quickstart</title>
        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jspm.io/system.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- The app component created in app.ts -->
        <my-app></my-app>
        <display></display>
        <script>
            System.import('app');
            System.import('displ');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="d:/npm/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import { Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
})

@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>',
})

// Component controller
export class MyAppComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Alice';
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

**displ.ts**

```
/// <reference path="d:/npm/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import { Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'display'
})

@View({
    template: '<h1>xxxHello {{ name }}</h1>',
})

// Component controller
export class DisplayComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Bob';
    }
}
```

The result is simply:

**Hello Alice**

Where did Bob go?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I realize that I was trying to do it the wrong way. My intention was to have the `display` component nested inside the `my-app` component, but the template of `my-app` didn't include the necessary ingredients:

1. It didn't include a `<display></display>` element. This was instead included in the top level `index.html` which was the wrong place for it.
2. The view annotation didn't include the display component as a directive reference.

In short, what I should have had was:

**app.ts (view annotation)**

```
@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1><display></display>',
    directives: [DisplayComponent]
})
```

And also I had to import my display component into `app.ts`:

```
import { DisplayComponent } from 'displ';
```

Comment: `bootstrap(DisplayComponent);` ?

Comment: @nada is it necessary to bootstrap every component?

Comment: usually we only need to bootstrap the root component, and we put the other components inside it included as directives. This was we only have to bootstrap the root. if you bootstrap the two components separately they will be two separate Angular 2 applications

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please add `bootstrap(DisplayComponent);` as [nada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449232/angular2-component-not-rendered#comment50866929_31449232) already points out.

From the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html):

> The bootstrap() function takes a component as a parameter, **enabling
>   the component (as well as any child components it contains) to render**.

So yes, you really need to call `bootstrap` for all components unless they are a child of another component.

Comment: Ok since I am so new with this, I just realized I had to include my 2nd component as a directive in the first...

Comment: Are there any ways that a component might contain other components other than by using directives?

Comment: @AviadP.: If you want to make a component a child of another component. I think the way you have it using a directive is the only way I know.

Comment: This does not work in recent versions of angular - adding a @directive to a Component is deprecated.